# "Double Wilson primes" - do they exist?

Tags: number-theory

Any prime number satisfies $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$

Any Wilson prime number satisfies $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {p^2}$ (Only known $5, 13, 563$, widely believed that there are infinite)

Is it possible for there to exist "double Wilson primes" - those which satisfy $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {p^3}$?

And, generally, do there exist primes which satisfy $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod {p^n}$?

Comment: One way to approach this: The reasoning for their being infinite is likely heuristic/probabilistic in nature. So if there are estimates on those grounds of the frequency of Wilson primes, presumably these can be adapted to give an estimated frequency of _double_ Wilson primes.

Comment: @Semiclassical But, if one were able to do that, surely one would also be able to say that they exist (which is all I'm asking)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible there exist such double Wilson primes, but no example is known and it is not unlikely none exists, however to prove this is likely rather hopeless.

To see why this is the case let us recall the heuristic for the infinitude of the WIlson primes. Set $w_p = ((p-1)! +1)/p$. This is an integer, large relative to $p$.
There are $p$ possibilities for the value of $w_p$ modulo $p$ and one can assume the are all more or less "equally likely" to occur. If  $w_p=0$ modulo $p$ then we have vound a Wilson prime.

Thus, we expect that the probability that $p$ is a Wilson prime is $1/p$. Now, $\sum_{p \le x} 1/p$  where the sum is only over the primes diverges, but slowly, namely about like $\log \log x$.

So, we expect roughly $\log \log x$ Wilson primes up to size $x$. This is not much, and in line with the fact there are only very few known, but still the number should be infinite.

Now, what about the double Wilson primes. Here, we need that $w_p$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $p^2$. Yet here there are $p^2$ possibilities, so we expect that the probability that $p$ is a double Wilson prime is $1/p^2$. Now, $\sum_{p } 1/p^2$ converges and thus we expect the number is finite.

Since we have not found any and following that heuristic the expected number still to be found is really small, namely $\sum_{p \ge N} 1/p^2$ where $N$ is the value up to which one tested already, it could be there are none. But it might be some is found eventually.

To prove anything here should be really difficult.

Comment: I'm glad that there's a good heuristic argument about double Wilson primes. (I know just enough about them to recognize when they'd be useful---hence my comment above---but not enough to actually answer a question like this.)

Comment: "one can assume the are all more or less "equally likely" to occur" no. I see no reason why you said this. The whole point of these number theoretic problems is that sometimes there is some structure, causing deviation from uniform distribution. I would appreciate if you deleted "it is not unlikely none exists, however to prove this is likely rather hopeless" since you provided no evidence

Comment: @mathworker21 the evidence I provided is that under the assumption that there is no hidden structure it is quite likely there is none (given the absence among small primes). That's a completely standard heuristic argument. It's not very sophisticated but quite often good enough. Classical conjectures such as infinitude of twin primes are (or at least were originally) mostly also based on just that type of reasoning.

Comment: I know much about these kinds of heuristics. However, you cannot deduce that it is rather hopeless to prove such a statement based on those heuristics because, like you said, it depends on the assumption that there is no hidden structure. There are many examples of structure existing but small examples not existing.

Comment: @mathworker21 please feel free to write the answer that you think should be given.

Comment: @quid just because I object to part of your answer doesn't mean I have one. In any event, I like the rest of your answer :) ... i'm not trying to be rude

Comment: @mathworker21 no worries. I concede there could be some argument exposing some reasonable "obstruction" that proves there are none. I just think this is unlikely. And if there is none it should be rather hopeless to prove that there just is none basically by chance, viz. it is likely rather hopeless.