# Stronger versions of Wilson's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

### Problem

> Let $c \in \mathbb{N}$ $;$ $\exists$ a prime $p$ for which:
>
> $$p^c \mid (p-1)!+1$$
>
> Does $\exists$ $M$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ $;$ $\forall$ $c \geqslant M$
> $;$ $\nexists$ $p$ satisfying the above?

---

### When $c$ = $1$

The statement is equivalent to **Wilson's Theorem**. For every prime $p$:
$$p \mid (p-1)!+1$$
**Proof:**

$\forall$ $x \in {1,2,...,p-1}$    $\exists!$  $ x' \in {1,2,...,p-1}$ ;

$x \cdot x'\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

$x=x' \iff p \mid x^2-1 \iff x = 1, x=p-1$

$(p-1)! = 1 \cdot (p-1) \cdot \prod{(x \cdot x')} \equiv 1^n \cdot (p-1) \equiv p-1 \pmod{p}$

$\implies p \mid (p-1)!+1$

QED

---

### When $c$ = $2$

We have the statement:
$$p^2 \mid (p-1)!+1$$
The only known primes that satisfy this are $5$, $13$ and $563$.

$(5-1)!+1 = 25 = 5^2$

$(13-1)!+1 = 479001601 = 13^2 \cdot 2834329$

$563^2 \mid (563-1)!+1 \approx 1.128 \cdot 10^{1303}$

Such primes $p$ are known as **Wilson Primes**. It is conjectured that there are infinitely many Wilson Primes. However, if there exists a fourth Wilson prime $p$, then $p>2 \cdot 10^{13}$.

---

### When $c \geqslant 3$

There are no known primes for which $p^3 \mid (p-1)!+1$ as if there is, then $p$ also has to be a Wilson Prime.

$(5-1)!+1 = 25 \equiv 25 \pmod{5^3}$

$(13-1)!+1 = 479001601 \equiv 676 \pmod{13^3}$

$(563-1)!+1 \equiv 91921010 \pmod{563^3}$

It is most likely due to following evidence that there exists an upper bound $M$ for which:
$$c \geqslant M \implies p^c \nmid (p-1)!+1$$
where $M \geqslant 3$.

- We consider $(p-1)!+1 \pmod{p^c}$
- We assume that every remainder divisible by $p$ (Wilson's Theorem) is equally probable.
- Thus, the probability of required remainder $0$ is $\frac{1}{p^{c-1}}$
- Thus, probable number of primes for given constant $c$ is:
  $$\sum{\frac{1}{p^{c-1}}} = P(c-1)$$
  where $P(x)$ is the **Prime Zeta Function**

When $c=2$, the expected number of Wilson primes is $P(1)$.
$$P(1)=\sum{\frac{1}{p}}$$
This sum is divergent. Thus, it is probable that there exist infinitely many Wilson primes.

---

**Proof:**

Define $N(x)$ to be the number of positive integers $n \leqslant x$ for which $p_i \nmid n$, where $i > j$ for constant $j$ and $p_i$ is the $i$th smallest prime. Then, we write:
$$n=k^2m$$
where $m$ is square-free.

As $m$ is square-free, and the only primes that divide it are $p_i$ for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant j$, it has $2^j$ possibilities.

$n^2 \leqslant x \implies n \leqslant \sqrt{x}$, thus giving $n$ a maximum of $\sqrt{x}$ possibilities.

$$\implies N(x) \leqslant 2^j\sqrt{x}$$

Assume the contrary, then for some $j$:
$$\sum_{i=j+1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_i} < \frac{1}{2}$$
We also have $x-N(x)$ is the number of numbers less than or equal to $x$ divisible by one or more of $p_i$ for $i>j$.
$$x-N(x) \leqslant \sum_{i=j+1}^\infty \frac{x}{p_i} < \frac{x}{2}$$
$$\implies 2^j\sqrt{x} > \frac{x}{2}$$
which is untrue for $x \geqslant 2^{2j+2}$

Thus the sum diverges. The divergence is similar to $\log{\log{x}}$ (Which is very slow).

---

### Probable Answer To Problem

When $c \geqslant 3$, the sum converges and is less than $1$.

When $c=3$, $P(c-1) \approx 0.45$

When $c=4$, $P(c-1) \approx 0.17$

When $c=5$, $P(c-1) \approx 0.07$

When $c=6$, $P(c-1) \approx 0.03$

When $c=7$, $P(c-1) \approx 0.002$

We now go on to show why there most probably exists a constant $M$ such as the one in the problem. Consider:
$$\sum_{i=3}^\infty P(i-1)$$

We have:

$$\sum_{i=3}^\infty P(i-1) < \sum{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}} = \sum{\biggl(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\biggl)} = 1$$

Thus, the probable sum of the number of primes that satisfy the statement for $c \geqslant 3$, including a prime $p$, $n-2$ times, if the maximum $c$ satisfied is $n$, is less than $1$. However, if the answer to the problem is false, then, the sum would be infinite.

Thus, it is highly unlikely for there to be a solution for $c \geqslant 3$ as the probable answer is less than $1$ but the actual answer would be a positive integer. However, it is almost impossible for the answer to the problem to be false, as the probable answer is less than $1$ but the actual answer would be infinite!

---

Any of the following:

- Any progress or insight
- Answers conditional on conjectures
- Polynomial or logarithmic non-trivial bounds on $M$

will be accepted and appreciated.

P.S. This question has been posted and answered in Math Overflow for the interested reader. Link:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311675/stronger-versions-of-wilsons-theorem

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Comment: Sorry for the discomfort

Comment: Actually, your problem is a small case of mine. I'll surely give it a go.

Comment: No, we can't. It probably will be again an open problem.

Comment: related : ["Double Wilson primes" - do they exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887640/double-wilson-primes-do-they-exist)

Comment: That is really good @mathlove. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding over all $c \ge 3$??? Can't you just deduce the finiteness of the sum for $c=3$ and be done?

Comment: Oh very sorry. I will make the edit

Comment: @DietrichBurde it is definitely an open problem since it is open for $c=2$

Comment: Please read the actual problem. It is about whether there exists an upper bound $M$. Even if $M=10^{10^{10}}$, the problem is solved. One just needs to show its existence, if not even its value, however big. This is hence a weaker problem, which is especially portrayed in the last part by probability using prime zeta function.

Comment: @mathworker $21$, I just realised that by adding for all $c \geqslant 3$, I get a stronger statement. I have made the edit above.

Comment: Here's the MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311675/stronger-versions-of-wilsons-theorem

Answer (score 1):

*Posted as an answer as it is too long for a comment*

Let it be some prime number $p$. It is known that the set of numbers $G=(Z/pZ)^x=\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ forms a group under multiplication; therefore, for each element $a$ of $G$, there is a unique multiplicative inverse $b$ in $G$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod p$. It is important to note that $1$ and $p-1$ are each one their own multiplicative inverse.

This implies that, if we take all the elements of $G$ in pairs $(a,b)$, each pair $(a_k,b_k)$ can be expressed as $c_{k}p+1$, where $c$ is some positive integer. And if we multiply them all, we get that $$(p-1)!=1(p-1)(c_1p+1)(c_2p+1)\dots(c_\left({\frac{p-1}{2}-1}\right)p+1)\equiv -1\pmod p$$

With this expression, it can be proved the conditional part of Wilson's theorem: if $p$ is some prime number, then $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod p$.

The existence of some $c_k=1$ is guaranteed for every odd prime number $p$ by the fact that $2b\equiv 1 \pmod p$ has the unique solution $b=\frac{p+1}{2}$ for every odd prime number $p$. As $2\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)=c_kp+1$, it follows that $c_k=1$ for the pair $(2,\frac{p+1}{2})$.

As a result, if we consider wlog the pair $(2,\frac{p+1}{2})$=$(a_1,b_1)$=$(c_{1}p+1)$, we have that

$$(p-1)!=1(p-1)(p+1)(c_2p+1)\dots(c_\left({\frac{p-1}{2}-1}\right)p+1)$$

$$(p-1)!=\left(p^2-1\right)\left((c_2p+1)(c_3p+1)\dots(c_\left({\frac{p-1}{2}-1}\right)p+1)\right)$$

If we consider the term $\left((c_2p+1)(c_3p+1)\dots(c_\left({\frac{p-1}{2}-1}\right)p+1)\right)$, it can be seen that it is of the form $p^{k}m+1$, where $k\geq 1$. Therefore, $$(p-1)!=\left(p^2-1\right)\left(p^{k}m+1\right)$$

Expanding the product, we get that $$(p-1)!=p^{k+2}m+p^2-p^{k}m-1=$$
$$(p-1)!=p^2\left(p^{k}m-p^{k-2}m+1\right)-1$$

Therefore, $$(p-1)!+1=p^2\left(p^{k}m-p^{k-2}m+1\right)$$

It follows that the term between brackets of the RHS is coprime to $p$, and thus $p^2$ is the maximum power possible dividing $(p-1)!+1$, *unless $k=2$ and $p\mid m+1$*.

Expanding the term $\left((c_2p+1)(c_3p+1)\dots(c_\left({\frac{p-1}{2}-1}\right)p+1)\right)$ it can be seen that $k=2$ only if $p\mid \sum_{i=2}^{\frac{p-1}{2}-1}c_i$, which constitutes a necessary condition for Wilson primes. However, proving that $p\nmid m+1$ for every prime number $p$ might be hard.